# Python 3.6 using defaultdict and Counter

Tags: python

I've only just started to learn Python and I have a task to complete as part of a learning program and it has me quite confused.  Yes, I have searched the s*%t out of this on here, youtube and other places and I just can't seem to connect the dots from what I have learned so far.  I am required to use 'defaultdict' and 'Counter' in python 3.6 to count the most frequent trades and their volumes from a comma delimited CSV file that is supplied in the learning console on the website which looks like this:

```
GOOG,100,900.10
MSFT,50,68.99
AAPL,100,152.92
IBM,5,151.95
GOOG,150,901.25
AAPL,50,152.25
TEAM,100,36.91
NVDA,75,117.88
INTC,200,36.24
IBM,10,151.91
AAPL,700,152.15
GOOG,100,900.99
GOOG,50,900.12
```

All I am supposed to do is count the most frequent trades, which has the most trades, and the total volume using the below code as a basis:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

def analyse(filename):

# TODO: initialise your counter here

with open(filename) as src:
    for line in src:
        inst, vol, price = line.split(',')
        vol = int(vol)
        price = float(price)
      # for trades, count in c.most_common(2):  --> I added this because this is how it was done in the tutorial

  # TODO: process data    

  # TODO: summarise results

  # You might want to use this output line (change variable names if you want)
        print(f'{inst:>5}:  {count} trade(s) total of {vol:4} shares, ${val:11,.2f}')  # I replaced 'val' with 'price'

if __name __ == '__main__': # I blanked this line out because nothing ever worked when it wasn't blanked out.
analyse('example.csv')


The #TODO's were already there.
```

The once I have added the code that I need it is supposed to print out:

```
Top 5 trades by number of trades:
GOOG:   4 trade(s) total of  400 shares, $ 360,302.50
AAPL:   3 trade(s) total of  850 shares, $ 129,409.50
 IBM:   2 trade(s) total of   15 shares, $   2,278.85
MSFT:   1 trade(s) total of   50 shares, $   3,449.50
TEAM:   1 trade(s) total of  100 shares, $   3,691.00
```

I just don't quite understand how this imports using the method in the code and then how to get the right printout.  All I have managed to get is every stock printing out in sequence.  Counting anything from a single list, such as stock names and how many times they appear, is fine, but now I have extra data that I need to count and it's not clear from the tutorial how it's done.  For example, the tutorial gives me this which makes sense:

```
from collections import defaultdict

volumes = defaultdict(int)
for trade in [100, 200, 300]:
    volumes['MSFT'] += trade # works every time

print('Total for MSFT:', volumes['MSFT'])
```

Thanks in advance for assistance, and apologies if I haven't been entirely clear.

~venam

Comment: Sounds like it would be much clearer to just made a trade class, make a list of that, then query that list as required. (Rather than parsing everything individually)

Comment: Don't be fooled. You will not become a programmer by watching YouTube videos. The fact that you put comments like "I blanked this line ..." tells me you are probably missing things from your class. I suggest you ask your teacher for help understanding the lessons.

Comment: @Sayse ehhh you can do this with a `defaultdict(Counter)` really easily.

Comment: @Sayse This is the way I am supposed to do it unfortunately, and I am aware that I need to use defaultdict and Counter, I just don't get how.  I've actually been stuck on this for nearly 1 week.

Comment: @Gicomo I know the bit I have blanked out is used for something but in this code I have no idea.  No teacher to ask which is why I'm asking here.  It's self paced and online.

Comment: Hint: you want to use a `defaultdict(Counter)`

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't include the file handling, function definitions, or pretty printing, but it should illustrate the way (I think, at least) they want you to apply those concepts. Also, if you're looking for total price, unless I'm missing something you should be multiplying the trade volume by the trade price.

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter


counts = defaultdict(Counter)

lines = """GOOG,100,900.10
MSFT,50,68.99
AAPL,100,152.92
IBM,5,151.95
GOOG,150,901.25
AAPL,50,152.25
TEAM,100,36.91
NVDA,75,117.88
INTC,200,36.24
IBM,10,151.91
AAPL,700,152.15
GOOG,100,900.99
GOOG,50,900.12""".split("\n")

for line in lines:
    symbol, volume, price = line.split(",")
    counts[symbol]["frequency"] += 1
    counts[symbol]["volume"] += int(volume)
    counts[symbol]["price"] += float(price) * counts[symbol]["volume"]

for symbol in sorted(counts, key=lambda s: counts[s]["frequency"], reverse=True)[:5]:
    print(symbol, counts[symbol])
```

`sorted()` in this case will get a list of the defaultdict's keys, and keys are what it will return (you could pass it `counts.keys()` instead of `counts` with the same effect).

I'd never actually used `Counter` before. Kind of an oddly specific thing to have sitting in a core library.

Answer (score -1):

Clearly I have come to the wrong place, for 2 reasons: being marked -2 for not doing proper research on my question is quite simply, BS! As stated in the question, I am required to solve this problem in a specific way and not even the python documentation clearly explains how to deal with this problem.  As you would know it explains what a defaultdict does, and what Counter does.  What it does not explain, and what nothing else has explained thus far, is what the data looks like once it's imported and how to manipulate it thereafter.  Might be simple to some, but not to me, which is why I have resorted to watching youtube videos.  And to my second reason, 2 "hints" that say I should use defaultdict(Counter)...what on earth does that mean?? Then other answers that say I won't become a programmer if I watch Youtube videos (yeah, dah) and to do the task a different way to what was in the stated question (yeah, dah, could have done that already with another method that doesn't use defaultdict. Ie. use pandas and / or numpy).

Things I have tried include:

initialising the defaultdict and counter below the "for line in src" part:

```
for line in src:
    inst, vol, price = line.split(',')
    trades = defaultdict(int)
    c = Counter()
```

All that does is spits out all of the data in pretty little rows, without finding the most common and adding up stuff.

The material that has been supplied to me just includes things like; here are 3 numbers, this is a list, and this adds them together; this is what defaultdict does; this is what Counter does etc etc. It is merely 5 small pages of instructions with a few snippets of code for examples, then the above task.

YES, I am new, and, YES, I am frustrated.

Comment: You should make this an edit to your question rather than an answer. Answering your own question is a good idea if no one else offers a working solution and you want to share the one you eventually find to help others who run into it in the future. It's understandable that you're frustrated, but venting about it like this really doesn't help anyone, including you.